# Check if user exist in Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, web

Hello im doing an app and I would like to check if the user exist, with the FB ghrap API, but I'm stuck here, witch is the best way for this? 
I checked the api doc and i cant figure out hot to do this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Not possible at all.

You can only get data of users who authorized your App. If a user authorized your App, he MUST exist. If he did not authorize your App, he is completely anonymous and there is no way to check if he exists.

Comment: Even with out a web application?                                     Some times I get and empty array of data, but as I'm concerned not allways got the user to not exists or viceversa. I will try out something more to see uni can get to a solution meanwhile

Answer (score 0):

There are some automated (but paid) solutions that could help you here. Essentially how they work is that you call their API with e-mail and phone number of the user and they do some kind of a magic behind the scenes. Afterwards they return a bunch of Social Media platforms that the user is (or is not) registered in:

- SEON: https://docs.seon.io/api-reference/ (See "Email API" and "Phone API")
- Jeff Data: https://www.jeff-app.com/jeff-data/social-account-presence (It seems to be possible to cherry-pick the platforms you need, reducing the price tag)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).